# Powershell: Custom object to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, object

I created custom object that basically stores Date and few integers in it's keys:

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    "Date" = $currentdate.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy');
    "Testers" = $totalTesterCount;
    "StNoFeedback" = $tester_status.NoFeedback;
    "StNotSolved" = $tester_status.NotSolved;
    "StSolved" = $tester_status.Solved;
    "StNoIssues" = $tester_status.NoIssues;
    "OSNoFeedback" = $tester_os.NoFeedback;
    "OSW7" = $tester_os.W7;
    "OSW10" = $tester_os.W10;
    "OfficeNoFeedback" =  $tester_Office.NoFeedback;
    "OfficeO10" = $tester_Office.O10;
    "OfficeO13" = $tester_Office.O13;
    "OfficeO16" = $tester_Office.O16;
}
```

I need to Output it to CSV file in a way that every value is written in new column. 
I tried using `$data | export-csv dump.csv`
but my CSV looks like that:

```
#TYPE System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
"Count","IsReadOnly","Keys","Values","IsFixedSize","SyncRoot","IsSynchronized"
"13","False","System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection","System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection","False","System.Object","False"
```

Not even close to what I want to achieve. How to get something closer to:

```
date,testers,stnofeedback....
04-03-2016,2031,1021....
```

I created the object because it was supposed to be easy to export it as csv. Maybe there is entirely different, better approach? Or is my object lacking something?

Comment: What research have you made on the subject ? Did you at helpful links such as https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849878.aspx ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't create an object, you created an ordered dictionary. A dictionary can't be exported to CSV-directly as it's a single object which holds multiple key-value-entries.

```
([ordered]@{}).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name              BaseType     
-------- -------- ----              --------     
True     True     OrderedDictionary System.Object
```

To export a dictionary you need to use `GetEnumerator()` to get the objects one by one, which would result in this CSV:

```
$data = [Ordered]@{
    "Date" = (get-date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
    "Testers" = "Hello world"
}

$data.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"Name","Key","Value"
"Date","Date","04-03-2016"
"Testers","Testers","Hello world"
```

If you want a single object, cast the hashtable of properties to a `PSObject` using `[pscustomobject]@{}`.

```
$data = [pscustomobject]@{
    "Date" = (get-date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
    "Testers" = "Hello world"
}

$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"Date","Testers"
"04-03-2016","Hello world"
```

Or if you're using PS 1.0 or 2.0:

```
$data = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    "Date" = (get-date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
    "Testers" = "Hello world"
}

$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"Testers","Date"
"Hello world","04-03-2016"
```

Comment: Nitpick: An ordered dictionary is an object.  It's just not an object that Export-Csv knows how to pick apart.  (hence PSCustomObject)

Comment: Actually it's a special type of collection-object that doesn't support foreach (pipeline included) without specifically calling `getenumerator()`. You would have the same problem if u used it in a c# foreach-loop. :-)